# Handling Video Stream in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, video-streaming

I want to stream (non-static) video files from an Express API to an Angular app. In the Express app, I have the following code that streams a video file to the response object.

### Express API

```js
...
res.writeHead(206, {
    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
    'Content-Length': file.length,
    'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
});
try {
    const stream = file.createReadStream();
    stream.pipe(res);
    res.on('close', () => console.log('download completed'));
    stream.on('data', () => console.log("data"));
    stream.on('error', () => console.log('stream error'));
} catch (error) {
    destroyClient(error as string)();
}
```

This part seems to work fine.

### Angular Service (Attempt 1)

```js
getMovie = (hash: string) =>
        this.http
            .get(`${this.BASE_URL}stream=${hash}`, {
                responseType: 'blob',
                withCredentials: true,
            })
            .pipe(
                map((blob) => {
                    const videoBlob = new Blob([blob], {type: 'video/mp4'});
                    return URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
                })
            );
```

Once the stream request is made, I log when each chunk is sent and in the network tab in Chrome, I can see that the content downloads (in chunks).
The issue I'm having is that the entire response finishes before the HTTP get observable calls the callback function (All +- 800MB of video is downloaded in the browser before the observable completes).

### Angular Service (Attempt 2)

```js
stream(hash: string) {
        return new Observable<Blob>((observer) => {
            const eventSrc = new EventSource(
                `${this.BASE_URL}stream=${hash}`, {
                  withCredentials: true,
                }
            );
            eventSrc.onmessage = (event) => observer.next(event.data);
            eventSrc.onerror = (error) => observer.error(error);
            };
        });
```

I read about SSE in Angular and the above code was suggested. This instantly throws an error since the stream is closed immediately. Do I need to stream the content in a different way from the backend or can I fix my Angular code somehow?